# How can I prevent keypress events from interfering with the browser's input support?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap's modal component to create an "Add User" dialog to my web app.  To make it easy for users to work quickly I want to make the escape an enter keys close and submit the form as would be expected.  After running into the usual troubles of divs not accepting input, and some elements under the modal getting focus I ended up just hooking a keypress event to 'document'.  This actually works great with one exception.

When entering data into the form the browser will sometimes show a suggestion box:
[image]

Hitting escape to close the suggestion box, or enter to select an element from it will unfortunately trigger a keypress event which causes the form to be closed or submitted.

Is there a way I can ignore the keypresses in this situation?  Do I need to be taking a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to add `autocomplete="off"` into the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `$(document).keyUp()` to bind your ESC and Enter key event. If so, you can try to add this code in that function to ignore keypress which pressed in a input tag:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.srcElement.tagName == 'INPUT'){
        return;
    }else{
        // Your code to bind function to exit div or submit
    }
});
```